# Cannot charge a token more than once

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim, applepay-web

We are trying to get a recurring billing setup whereby we can charge the same token on variable intervals and possibly variable amounts with Apple Pay and CIM. However it appears the tokens from Apple are one-time-use.

We can successfully get a token from Apple, and successfully create a customer profile at Authorize.net using that token where the card is authorized and the test transaction is voided. But that's it. All subsequent transactions will fail with response code 2 (transaction declined).

By the same token (ha!) if we choose to charge the token initially (rather than create a customer profile) that also works, but then we are not able to create a customer from the transaction.

It's as though these tokens are one-use only, which of course does not work in a monthly subscription model.

Has anyone successfully implemented CIM with Apple Pay? What are the tricks to allow for more than one charge?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an in-App payment with Apple and Google pay, you have some parameters to set that can determine if this is a one time payment or not.

I’m not familiar with Auth.Net’s implementation, but this is probably something you have to do on your side before sending them the token.
Also to note, even if you set it up correctly a user can revoke it later on, so these transactions are usually not used for recurring billing.

For us, we chose to just have a basic payment form on our site which Safari or Chrome will autofill from the users wallet, but does so with the actual card information and not a tokenized PAN.

We only use our terminals from USIO for Apple and Google pay, and on most of those transactions, we can use the token to charge the card in the future.